# Powerquery: split text from different columns to same rows

Tags: powerquery

I have:

```
column1 | column2 | colum3
a;b;c   | x;y;z   | door;house;tree
```

Desired result using Excel powerquery:

```
 a      | x       | door
 b      | y       | house
 c      | z       | tree
```

I tried with:
Text.Split([column1],";") and expand to new lines, obtaining:

```
a
b
c
```

However when tried the same with other values, new lines are created instead to use the existent ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    rec = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,0,0,(a,b,c)=>Text.Split(a,";"),{"column1", "column2", "column3"}){0},
    table = #table(Record.FieldNames(rec),List.Zip(Record.FieldValues(rec)))
in
    table
```

Comment: It only works with the first line. But in any case thanks your example I learned the key for the trick is to use "List.Zip". Using it, I solved the problem. Thank you!